# Coercive nature of Bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the following Bilinear form
$$a(u,v)=\int_{a}^{b}u(x)v(x)\alpha (x)dx$$
where $\alpha (x)$ is any continuous function.
We need to show it's coercive nature ($a(u,u)\geq c\|u\|^2$). Should we consider any more properties on $\alpha (x)$? What I did was
\begin{equation}
a(u,u)=\int_{a}^{b}u(x)u(x)\alpha (x)dx
\\=\int_{a}^{b}u^2(x)\alpha (x)dx
\end{equation}
After this I am stumped. $\alpha (x)$ has a particular structure, but it's very long. Can't we just assume continuity of $\alpha (x)$ and show the result? The norm is ($\|u\|=\sqrt{\int_a^b u^2(x)dx}$)

Comment: "Coercive" means various things: what do you mean exactly? (I understand that you need $a(u, u)\ge C\|u\|^2$, but you should specify the norm you want)

Comment: The post has nothing to do with linear algebra, in particular not with numerical linear algebra, so I edited them out. Also, the question is not well defined: you must specify the norms.

Comment: you're going to have to provide some details about $\alpha$. Without more info, the bilinear form may fail to be coercive.

Comment: See I am not able to find a particular form of $\alpha(x)$. We can restate the question saying what kind of $\alpha(x)$ we get coercive nature

Comment: It would be enough to have $\alpha$ bounded below by a positive constant. You can't do much better than that, because if $\alpha$ has a zero (even if it is otherwise positive) then functions $u$ localized near that zero will tend make $a(u,u)$ small relative to $\| u \|^2$. If $\alpha$ is ever negative then coercivity fails even more spectacularly.